# Just started with Silverlight, can I send data to my embeded silverlight "widget" from main web application page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, widget

Essentially I added a new Silverlight project into an existing web application (C#) that I've been working on. I did this in order to make use of the nice Telerik Controls for silverlight. More precisely, the ChartView Control ([link](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/controls_/chartview.aspx)).

I'd like to use this to chart out revenue generated by say, a customer, over the last month.

So for example, let's say i have an .aspx page that brings up a customer based on his GUID (I fecth his data via an api call to the back-end application). In the result I'll have all of that customers relevant infortation plus a list of amounts for money for the last 30 days (so thirty values) as an array.

If I create a Silverlight chart and embed it into that customer page, How can I pass in that array of money amounts so that I can plot a chart with my silverlight control??? Or any other data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using WCF is one good approach, especially if you've already got WCF up and running for other purposes. But there are other ways to do it as well, particularly if the data already exists on the web page by the time the Silverlight application is loaded. Two of them include:

(1) If the data is static, and not likely to change over the lifetime of the page, you can pass data into the Silverlight application using the "initParams" parameter (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004(VS.95).aspx)).

(2) A more flexible approach, but one which could take a bit more work, is to expose some of your Silverlight application's methods to JavaScript, and pass data and other parameters in that way (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645085(VS.95).aspx)).

Comment: +1  I'd go with the javascript way, either as Ken says by exposing the silverlight methods to javascript. Or my preferred choice the other way around, putting the money values into a javascript function that you can call from within the silverlight application instead.

Comment: @Chris - Agreed, the call stack could go from Silverlight->JavaScript as well. But if the SL applet is just a chart, the trigger for the data change is likely to happen outside the SL app, and hence it might be better to "push" the data into the SL app rather than have the SL app "pull" it.

Comment: I hadn't considered that, you're correct a push would be better. Thanks for the pointer =)

Answer (score 1):

You need a WCF service which exposes data on the server and a WCF proxy in the Silverlight application to be able to call server-side methods. When the data is transfered from the server to the client, you can bind it to your chart to show it at the client side.

Before you design your services, read more on how to properly make use of the Data Transfer Object pattern.

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/12/generic-dto-model-and-other-silverlight.html

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight was at first supported with javascript, so one way would be to feed your Silverlight app from javascript client side if the html already contains data to display or call ajax if you don't have WCF.

Here is an example how to send data into Silverlight via javascript

[link](http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2009/07/31/Send-data-from-javascript-to-Silverlight.aspx)